# Fullcalendar.js allDay parameter returned from MySql using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get FullCalendar working on my Codeigniter app, but coming across a problem with the events showing as all day from my JSON feed.

I've found that setting "allDay":false fixes the problem (tested with a static json file) but when i store that value in a mysql DB, then return the data and run the JSON encode, it converts the False into a string, which cause the event to show as all day!

Does anybody know how i can store true or false in my DB (i'm currently storing as text) and return it to my json feed without it being a string? I've tried casting and converting but can't get anything to work!

Examples of my model/controller/json feed below;

Thanks in advance;

Model function

```
function show_installs()
{       
    return $this->db->query(
    "SELECT id, client_name as title, start, end, concat('/planner/view_install/',id) as url
    FROM installs WHERE completed != 2"
    )->result();            
}
```

Controller function

```
function json_installs()
{
    $this->load->model('installs_model');
    $data = array();        
    if($query = $this->installs_model->show_installs())
    {
        $data = $query;
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;
}
```

JSON Feed (That doesnt work because of the " around false)

```
[
   {
      "id":"18",
      "title":"John",
      "allDay":"false",
      "start":1339585200,
      "end":1339592400,
      "url":"\/planner\/view_install\/18"
   },
   {
      "id":"19",
      "title":"Mike",
      "allDay":"false",
      "start":"1339585200",
      "end":"1339592400",
      "url":"\/planner\/view_install\/19"
   }
]
```

Any help would be really appreciated - i just need to get those bloomin quote marks off from false/true and it would work perfectly!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change the column type in your DB to be boolean instead of text? You could also parse your $json object to convert all booleans_as_text to booleans before you set it in the calendar - quick googling found me this:

```
for(var i=0; i<$json.length; i++)
  $json[i]=/^true$/i.test($json[i]);
```

You could also set the `allDayDefault` to `false` to avoid set allday: false in each event.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help - great idea about looping through the JSON data and replacing "false" with false - i've tried the code above but it doesn't seem to work, could you possibly explain it through for me? Again, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Hi there - i manage to get it working using $json = str_replace( '"allDay":"0"', '"allDay":false', $json ); - this seems to work but not sure if it's the best way of doing it?

Comment: I think you are right. It says in the fullcalendar docs :"don't put false/true all day param between QUOTES because they are boolean values". The problem is that PHP JSON_ENCODE adds quotes to any value. Your solution may be the only workaround.